# Error while using “ElementRef” in exported component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using `ElementRef` in the CommentComponent which is exported to others modules like ArticleModule, ProductModule etc...

```
// CommentModule
@NgModule({
    exports: [ CommentComponent ],
    declarations: [ CommentComponent ],
    providers: [ CommentService]
})

export class CommentModule { }


// Comment Component (belongs to CommentModule)
@Component({
    selector: 'comments',
    templateUrl: 'comment.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['comment.component.scss']
})
export class CommentComponent implements OnInit {

    suggOnTyping: string = 'hidden';
    constructor(private _eref: ElementRef){}

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    onClickOutside(event: any) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (!this._eref.nativeElement.contains(event.target))
            this.suggOnTyping = 'hidden';
    }
}


// Article Module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        CommentModule,
        ArticleRoutingModule],
    declarations: [ ArticleComponent ],
    providers: [ArticleService, CommentService, CommentComponent],
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

ArticleComponent calls the CommentComponent from view like this:

```
<div class="article">
    .......
    <comments></comments>
</div>
```

Now when I'm trying to route through ArticleComponent, I'm getting:

> core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgClass -> ElementRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgClass -> ElementRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgClass -> ElementRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgClass -> ElementRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!

It seems ElementRef cannot pass through 'provider' because when I remove it from CommentComponent everything works fine.

What is the problem ?

I'm using Angular 6 by the way

Comment: add --preserve-symlinks in your build command

Comment: Move `CommentComponent` from `providers` array to `declarations`

Comment: @yurzui CommentComponent belongs to CommentModule which mean it is already declared there ! You can see CommentModule inside ArticleModule imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `CommentComponent` from providers list of `AritcleModule`. `CommentComponent` is already declared in  `CommentModule`.

```
// Article Module

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ArticleComponent], 
    providers: [ArticleService, CommentService, CommentComponent ], //<-- remove from here
    schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
```

Remove `ElementRef` from `constructor` which is throwing this error and if you want to access the element then you can put the reference for element and use @ViewChild decorator in ts file.

#### Example :

html

```
<div #ele>hello/div> <!-- element reference goes here -->
```

ts

```
@ViewChild("ele") _eref: ElementRef;
```

Comment: CommentComponent belongs to CommentModule which mean it is already declared there ! You can see CommentModule inside ArticleModule imports.

Comment: Then you can simply remove it from the `ArticleModule` and do not forget  to export `CommentComponent` from `CommentModule`.

Comment: CommentComponent is already exported by CommentModule ! Check the update

Comment: Then you are all set. It should be working then if not then share the error you are getting now .

Comment: Same error as described in post ! The problem is with `ElementRef` because when I remove it from CommentComponent everything works well.

Comment: I think `ElementRef` refuses to be exported(to be provided) !

Comment: Is there a way to bypass this ? I really need `ElementRef` in CommentComponent :(

Comment: Very nice ! Works great thank you so much ! You can remove the first answer section ;)

Comment: @AmadouBeye is there some missing comment? What was the solution?